# Collision of axes labels and ticks

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to prevent ugly collision of axes labels and axes number like in the following examples, without the need of adding white space:

#### Plot1:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"ω", Subscript["E","F"], "Log[σ(ω)]"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[16]]
```

[image: Plot1]

To avoid this distant axes label "Log[$\sigma(\omega)]" one can rotate it, but then:

#### Plot2:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x]Cos[y],{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi},
    AxesLabel->{"ω",Subscript["E","F"],Rotate["Log[σ(ω)]",90 Degree]},
    LabelStyle->Directive[16]
]
```

[image: Plot2]

I cannot imagine that using a 2-dimensional column with one element `"Log[σ(ω)]"` and the other a blank square is the only solution to cure Plot2. Is there a nice solution to prevent such an overlay?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could specify the option `ImageSize ->600` (or something large enough to you taste). However, that would change the proportions of other parts of the plot, and you may not want that.

So instead I'd suggest adding some offset around the labels by using `Framed` as follows:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"ω", Subscript["E", "F"], 
   Framed["Log[σ(ω)]", 
    FrameStyle -> None, 
    FrameMargins -> 20
   ]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[16]
]
```

[image: framed]

To see what this does in more detail, you could leave out the option `FrameStyle -> None`, or add the option `Background -> Yellow` to the `Framed` command.

Comment: Congrats on your 10K!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks - you're almost there too! BTW, how many points do we need in order to win a prize?

Comment: Enough to beat [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).