# axis label formatting in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Plot3D[Cx + p, {Cx, 0, 1}, {p, 0.5, 1},
AxesLabel -> {"Cx", "p", "Val"},
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}]
```

which will give me the following plot:
[image]

The z-axis label overlaps with the z-axis numbers. How can I prevent the overlap between the label and the numbers on the axis?

Comment: And [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/axeslabel-in-histogram3d-unreadable)?

Comment: @bobthechemist yes. thanks for pointing out