# Aligning the axeslabel in a 3D list plot ($x,y,z$) (edited)?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code

```
plot = ListPlot3D[mydata5, DataRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
                 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .7}, 
                 AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[t, l], FontSize -> 21], 
                   Style[Subscript[t, u], FontSize -> 21], 
                   Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, a]/
                         Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, m], FontSize -> 21]}, 
                 BaseStyle -> 18]
```

For plotting a 3D $60\times 60$ data. Here is the output[image]

Obviously the problem is at the axes label at left up side. It overlaps with the numbers. I am just using rotate sign and do the rotation and scaling manually. This view was the nicest view but I cannot play with increasing or decreasing the indent of the axeslabels. Is it possible to add it inside **ListPlot3D**?

I am sorry, but I dont know how to load the data here but I think it might not be a crucial issue.

**EDIT:(29.10.2014)**

I checked the following questions and the answers therein:

[Collision of axes labels and ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/collision-of-axes-labels-and-ticks)

[AxesLabel in Histogram3D unreadable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/axeslabel-in-histogram3d-unreadable)

These answer also don't help me because they don't have Subscript notations in the Style, instead they have "".

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[pF];
pF[l_: 0, r_: 5] := Pane[Style[#, FontSize -> Large],FrameMargins -> {{l, r}, {0, 0}}] &;

{xl, yl, zl} = {Style[Subscript[t, l], FontSize -> 21], 
   Style[Subscript[t, u], FontSize -> 21], 
   Style[Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, a]/
     Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, m], 
    FontSize -> 21]};

mydata5 = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
Row[ListPlot3D[mydata5, DataRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, BaseStyle -> 18,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .7}, 
    AxesLabel -> {xl, yl, pF[0, #]@zl} ] & /@ {0, 20, 40}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

You can also use `Framed` instead of `Pane`:

```
ClearAll[pF2];
pF2[l_: 0, r_: 5] := Framed[Style[#, FontSize -> Large], FrameStyle->None,
                     FrameMargins -> {{l, r}, {0, 0}}] &;
```

Comment: woow! thats working really great. Once again thank you very much for your help. I was really struggling for a very easy looking problem, which turned out to be really non-trivial. I also find it strange because this is really something basic and mathematica shouldnt have such a problem.

Comment: seyhmus, thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to add several white spaces i.e. use something like `AxesLabel -> "a   "`. You can use `Manipulate` to adjust the number of white spaces:

```
With[{p = Plot3D[Abs[x + I y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]}, 
 Manipulate[Show[p, AxesLabel -> "|z|" <> ConstantArray[" ", n]], {n, 0, 10, 1}]]
```

[image]

---

As suggested by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) in the comment below, we can achieve exact positioning with `Spacers`:

```
With[{p = Plot3D[Abs[x + I y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]}, 
 Manipulate[Show[p, AxesLabel -> Row[{"|z|", Spacer[s]}]], {s, 0, 100}]]
```

Comment: Instead of `ConstantArray[" ", n]` you could use `Spacer[w]` for exact positioning.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh, I didn't know this function! Added.

Comment: I have a problem with spacer. It is spacing not only $z$ axis but also $x$ and $y$ axeses, which must normally not happen.

Comment: I have checked in v.8.0.4 and v.10.0.1: with `Spacer` the behavior is exactly as shown in the animation, but more smooth.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Sorry, I can't understand what you mean, I just checked my approach with kguler's data, the behavior is exactly the same at least in my computer. Can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot3D[29000.0 Abs[x + I y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .7},
 ImageSize -> 300,
 AxesLabel -> Row[{Spacer[30], 
    Style[ Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, a]/Subsuperscript[
    Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, m]], Spacer[30]}]
]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: You can in the Row use the `Spacer `. Like this:  `Row[{Style[
    Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, a]/
     Subsuperscript[Subscript["E", Subscript[N, 0]], m, m]], 
   Spacer[30]}]]

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Thanks :)

Comment: $z$ axis is okay but $x$ and $y$ are also spaced, which is not desired. Do you have any idea to apply it only to the $z$ axis?