# Manually assigning Axes label position in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, labeling

How can I adjust the position of axes labels with respect to the axes they are bound? Like shifting slightly right or left. I do not what to destroy the graphics' dynamics and render it 2D.

```
p[r_, coupon_, n_, value_] := (coupon*value)/r (1 - 1/(1 + r)^n) + 
  value/(1 + r)^n

Plot3D[Evaluate[
  p[r/100, c, n, 1]^-1*D[p[r/100, c, n, 1], r] /. r -> 6], {n, 1, 
  20}, {c, 0, 0.1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"years", "coupon %", 
   Rotate[ "Price change", 90 Degree]}]
```

Comment: See [Collision of axes labels and ticks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/collision-of-axes-labels-and-ticks) and [AxesLabel in Histogram3D unreadable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/axeslabel-in-histogram3d-unreadable)

Comment: These seem to be rather indirect tricks to circumvent the main problem. How can I just directly assign positions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I just directly assign positions?

You can do it manually by creating `Graphics3D` text objects and positioning them alongside the plot.  You can specify their coordinates using `Scaled` coordinates,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[
   p[r/100, c, n, 1]^-1*D[p[r/100, c, n, 1], r] /. r -> 6], {n, 1, 
   20}, {c, 0, 0.1}],
 Graphics3D[Text["years", Scaled[{0.45, -.15, 0}]]],
 Graphics3D[Text["coupon %", Scaled[{-.15, .85, 1.1}]]],
 Graphics3D[
  Text[Rotate["Price Change", 90 Degree], 
   Scaled[{-0.05, -.15, 0.75}]]]]
```

[image]

Or absolute coordinates,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[
   p[r/100, c, n, 1]^-1*D[p[r/100, c, n, 1], r] /. r -> 6], {n, 1, 
   20}, {c, 0, 0.1}],
 Graphics3D[Text["years", {6, -.02, -.18}]],
 Graphics3D[Text["coupon %", {-2, .07, 0.04}]],
 Graphics3D[
  Text[Rotate["Price Change", 90 Degree], {-1, -.02, -.03}]]]
```

[image]

Interestingly, the normal trick of using `Epilog->Inset[....]` will not work here.  It's possible to put the text in the graphics this way, but when you go to rotate the graphics with your mouse, the text stays in the same place.

Comment: is there a way to make the alignment of labels along the axis?

Answer (score 16):

### Edit in response to the comment about Dynamic Rotating (1/3/17)

Make a function with three angles as its arguments. The three angles control the rotation of the three axis labels.

```
f[xangle_, yangle_, zangle_] := 
Module[{}, 
labelx = Style[Rotate["years", xangle], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold,
 12];
 labely = 
 Style[Rotate["coupon %", yangle], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 12];
 labelz = 
Style[Rotate["Price change", zangle], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
 12];

 fig = Overlay[{plot, 
 Graphics[{}, AspectRatio -> (h + b + t)/(w + l + r1), 
  ImageSize -> {w + l + r1, h + b + t}, ImagePadding -> 0, 
  Epilog -> {Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], labelx]], 
    Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt1], labelz]], 
    Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt2], labely]]}]}, All, 2]
 ]
```

Now make three slider that can dynamically rotate the above three angles

```
Slider[Dynamic[xangle], {0 Degree, 360 Degree, 0.5 Degree}]
Slider[Dynamic[yangle], {0 Degree, 360 Degree, 0.5 Degree}]
Slider[Dynamic[zangle], {0 Degree, 360 Degree, 0.5 Degree}]
```

Then call the function with the same dynamic argument. Now you also have control over the rotation. Use the slider to set up the angles as shown below.

[image]

Freeze the final image after you have set everything as before by using

```
finalFig = 
fig /. Locator[x_, y_] :> Inset[y, x] /. Dynamic :> Identity
```

Regarding saving the image you should be able to export it cleanly with `Export` command. But before exporting it is good habit to initialize the saving directory to the current notebook directory. I always use the following initialization in all my notebooks.

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
 SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"];
 $HistoryLength = 0;
```

Now the exported image will be saved in the same directory where your notebook is saved.

```
 Export["1.jpg", finalFig, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

---

### Original Answer

There's a easier way to position elements by using `Dynamic` locator.

Let us define some constants to be used later.

```
pt = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}];    (*initial position of label1*)
pt1 = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}];   (*initial position of label2*)
pt2 = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}];   (*initial position of label3*)
{w, h} = {400, 250};        (*width & height*)
{{l, r1}, {b, t}} = {{80, 40}, {60, 10}};    (*padding controls*)
```

Plot the function without any label.

```
plot = Plot3D[Evaluate[p[r/100, c, n, 1]^-1*D[p[r/100, c, n, 1], r] /. 
r -> 6], {n, 1, 20}, {c, 0, 0.1}, 
ImageSize -> {w + l + r1, h + b + t}, ImagePadding -> {{l, r1}, {b, t}}]
```

Create the labels separately with controls over its styling.

```
labelx = Style["years", FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 12];
labely = Style["coupon %", FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 12];
labelz = Style[Rotate["Price change", 90 Degree], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 12];
```

Now we can `Overlay` the plot and labels including `Dynamic` locator so that we can move all the labels independently to any desired location as seen in the following gif.

```
  fig = Overlay[{plot, 
  Graphics[{}, AspectRatio -> (h + b + t)/(w + l + r1), 
  ImageSize -> {w + l + r1, h + b + t}, ImagePadding -> 0,
  Epilog -> {Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], labelx]], 
  Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt1], labelz]], 
  Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt2], labely]]}]}, All, 2]
```

[image]

After you have placed all the labels to your satisfaction you can then freeze their final position.

```
 finalFig = fig /. Locator[x_, y_] :> Inset[y, x] /. Dynamic :> Identity
```

Comment: This is a neat trick.  You should note that if you want to resize or rotate the 3D figure, you need to do that before applying the dynamic stuff, since `Overlay` makes it so you can't do that stuff anymore.

Comment: Yes that's true but I rotated the plot and choose a particular orientation and then again ran the plot but the orientation didn't carry through to the `Overlay` part. The only way I see is to first rotate the figure to your liking, then cut it and paste it inside `AbsoluteOptions["paste figure here", ViewPoint]`. Then set the value you just found inside the `Plot3D` command.

Comment: I find that I can just copy and paste the graphic into the `fig=Overlay[{____,...` command in place of the word `plot`, and if I make adjustments there they carry through to the output.

Comment: Yep that works. But I was thinking about dynamically updating this as well and found this : 
`http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view`.
 You define `vp = Options[Plot3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]]` and set option `ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]` inside the `Plot3D`.  This is effortless.

Comment: Great answer to a quite annoying problem. However, I cannot save the graphic in any format (right click on graphic --> save graphic as ...). I just end up with a white plot. Strangely, the axes are shown. In addition, it would be cool to be also able to rotate each axes label so that they are parallel to the axes. Is there a possibility to incorporate that here?

Comment: @Niki Please see the edit. For saving use `Export` command as shown in the edit. I have also shown how to rotate the labels dynamically.