# Positioning of axis labels

Tags: plotting

I have 3D parametric plot which has Log-Log-Linear scales and I want to reposition my axis labels, especially label called $\Pi (W)$ in the middle of the interval 0.1-0.5 on logarithmic scale on the picture. My code is:

```
f1 = {x, 1, 1.1102411875245117 (1/x)^1.2542211266950642};
a3 = ParametricPlot3D[f1, {x, 1, 80}, 
AxesLabel -> {"W", "Year", "\[CapitalPi] (W)"}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Identity, "Log"}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Automatic, 
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}]
```

How can I reposition them? Is there any function like manipulate that can do that?

Comment: You may need to just position them manually:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105719/9490

Comment: Must have missed it while searching, thank you.