# Using ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am very new with Mathematica. I am using ListPlot3D to graph a plane in 3 coordinated axes. I am using the following code:

```
c = ListPlot3D[a,AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["A1", Bold, Black, 16]], 
    Text[Style["A2", Bold, Black, 16]],Text[Style["A3", Bold, Black, 16]]}, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> All,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow}, 
  ViewPoint -> {90, 45, 50},PlotRange -> {{0, 130}, {0, 130}, {0, 130}}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]]
```

But I need to place the label axes at the end of the axis. Could you please can help me with this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105719/24710