# How put 3D axes labels at positive ends of axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

As the output of the following code shows, by default *Mathematica* does *not* necessarily place the axes label for 3D graphics at the positive ends of the axes, for axes emanating from the origin.

In the graphical output, the y-axis label is at the *negative* end, contrary to the way a mathematician would ordinarily label such a figure.

Is there some option to have the labels put at the positive ends?

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[θ], 2 Sin[θ], 0}, {θ, 0, π/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-2, 2}},
    Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] &) /@ {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: y-axis label is at negative end of axis]

Comment: I don't think so, but it shouldn't be difficult to do with `Text`.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105715/9490

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[\[Theta]], 2 Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 2}}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] &) /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewAngle -> Pi/8]
```

[image: fig1]

Second model

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[\[Theta]], 2 Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 2}}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 16], Style[y, 16], Style[z, 16]}]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Yes, I know about `ViewAngle`; and in fact one can just manually drag the 3D graphic to reorient the axes like that and so have axes "properly" labeled at their positive ends. But I was hoping for another option that forced the labels to the positive ends, no matter what the orientation.

Comment: And the method of using `ViewAngle`, unfortunately, does not work if I give the parameter a variable terminal value and put the resulting `ParametricPlot` expression inside a `Manipulate` where that terminal value is the control variable.

Comment: Correction to my comments: your input does *not* produce with Mathematica 11.3 the output you show! The axes retain their position as if the `ViewAngle` option were not there.

Comment: @murray I just answered your question. If you want to ask another question ask it.

Comment: My ` $Version Out[]= "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"`

Comment: My $Version: "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)".

Comment: it's funny that the result depends on the operating system. ok i'll look for another method

Comment: @murray I added a second code using `Style[]`

Comment: No, the second model produces the same (undesirable) result as the first with macOS.

Comment: @murray it looks like a bug.

Comment: According to the documentation, `ViewAngle` should *not* change the location or orientation of the axes! All it does is change a camera's *opening* angle from which the graphic is viewed, thereby in effect moving the viewed object closer or further away. The appropriate option seems to be `ViewPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't understand why, by default under the macOS front end, the original code oriented the axes with the positive x-axis pointing backwards, the following with use of `ViewPoint` gives the result I was looking for.

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[\[Theta]], 2 Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 2}}, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] &) /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 2}]
```

[image: Orientation with positive x-axis pointing forward]

Comment: this is not a solution. if you rotate the shape, the position of the labels changes.